# Anaconda Installer (Fedora/Cent/RH/Qubes)- CLI Disk Prep Prior to Install

Tags: installation, centos, redhat, fedora, qubes-os

I'm looking to have root on a RAID BtrFS built on a number of luks disks.  I typically do this on Debian or Ubuntu by preparing my disks before-hand, then running the install into those disks.  At the end, I need to pivot into the new system to modify crypttab and fstab.

I'm trying the same thing with Qubes, which uses the Anaconda installer. When I get to the GUI partitioner, the BtrFS appears under the "Unknown" dropdown, but if I try to set "mount point to "/" and then "Update Settings," it errors with "You must create a new filesystem on the root device."  (But there is already one there.)  If I use "+" instead, I am told "Not enough free space for thin provisioning."  The installer is clearly confused about how much space is available: "Available space 992.5 KiB," "Total space 238.47 GiB."  In fact, there is 932.35GiB in the RAID'ed BtrFS.

If I just open the luks devices, but put no FS in there, then all /dev/mapper/luks* devices appear in the partitioner under the "Unknown" dropdown, but choosing "New mount points will use the following partitioning scheme: Btrfs," none of the devices allow me to associate a mount point. It's greyed out, or if I try to use "+" and test it with a single disk, it comes back with an error "Not enough disks for single."  (But I have multiple LUKS disks there!)

Trying without any prior formatting, neither luks nor Btrfs, I find that the partitioner can't handle bare disks.  It wants a partition table (which I don't).

Does anyone have a way through this?

Edit: It appears there are [serious issues with this installer](https://groups.google.com/forum/?_escaped_fragment_=topic/qubes-users/bN4KmHA5sxA).

Answer (score 1):

The answer to all of this appears to be: "Don't try to fight the Anaconda, as you *will* lose."  Despite the access to a root terminal (Control-Alt-F1 reaches a tmux session, Control-b 2, reaches a terminal with root privileges), you must return to the graphical installer, which is too limited to allow any headway, particularly with BtrFS disks.  Anaconda sees BtrFS not as a filesystem, but as a device, and this makes problems insurmountable.

The solution is to do a dummy install and then modify all disks, editing crypttab, fstab, /etc/default/grub as needed.  Then pivot in and run `dracut -f`, along with `grub2-mkinstall` if needed.  Also, if necessary, `grub2-install`.

One advantage of BtrFS in this process, is that it's possible to avoid having to use a live-DVD or Anaconda's rescue shell to make changes in a system "at rest", afterward pivoting in to run `dracut` et al.  You'd just use `btrfs device add` to add a device to the root, and then `btrfs device remove` the original.  Then make relevant changes to the original partitions, afterwards reversing the `add`/`remove`.  So it's possible to make changes by moving back and forth from one disk to the other.